# Retrieving a row outside loop

Tags: php, laravel

I have this function in controller:

```
   public function index()
      {

          $call=45;
          $show = DB::select('select * from users where position="keeper" ');
          return View('index',['users'=>$show,'call'=>$call]);  
     }
```

In the view i have this piece of code:

```
  Call: {{$call}}    
  Position: {{$users->position}}     //what is the wrong with this line? everything is fine if i remove this line.

    @foreach ($users as $u)
    {{$u->id}}
    {{$u->name}}
    {{$u->email}} 
     @endif
```

> Error: Trying to get property of non-object

same works well with loop:

```
 @foreach($users as $r)
{{$r->position}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: please show more of your code. You should probably name variables differently if they are arrays. eg change user to $users. Also you aren't passing call into the view. Only the $show. Change the View('index', ['user' => $show, 'call' => $call])

Comment: the code inside foreach is working which is exact similar to the line above.@Brett

Comment: The error you see because of the variable `$user->position` which is not available outside the loop. You must use this inside the loop. Looking at your query , you are selecting users who have "keeper" position. So , why don't you print static "Keeper" in your blade view ?

Comment: it may not always be 'keeper'. i have another function where position can be any.  `{{$users[0]->position}}` found somewhere that $users is an array and accessing first element from any position solved it.@MD.AtiqurRahman

Comment: @MD.AtiqurRahman thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 0):

> $show = DB::select('select * from user where position="keeper" ');

this query returns multi-dimensional object. That's why you can not access it's property like this `$user->position`.

To fix the issue, try like this:

```
public function index()
{
     $call=45;
     $show =  DB::select('select * from user where position = "keeper" limit 1')[0];
     return View('index', ['user' => $show, 'call' => $call]); 
}
```

Comment: i am using raw sql statement and i have to change many codes in other functions too for this.

Comment: even `{{$user->id}}` is not accessed outside for loop??

Comment: {{$user->id}} is not accessed outside for loop because there is another `index` between `user` and `id`. To the index use `dd($user);`

Comment: that will not execute the loop, i guess.

Comment: Yes. It won't excute the loop. You can the properties directly like this `$user->id; $user->name;.....` so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way..

```
public function index()
  {

    $call=45;
    $show = DB::table('user')->where("position", "keeper")->first();
    return View('index',['user'=>$show,'call'=>$call]);   
 }
```